# Prepending $ to result SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to a prepend a `$` at the beginning of my result using SQL. What is the best way to go about it with it having the same functionality as this line of code has :

```
CAST(AVG(e.[myAmount]) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS 'Total Amount'
```

I know I can do convert it to `VARCHAR` and add it to beginning of statement, but it then gets rid of my average functionality.

Comment: You should handle presentation in the presentation layer and let the database just send you the raw data.  As noted below: what if there are multiple currency types?  You may _know_ that there aren't any now, but it'll be easier long run for you if you plan for it now.

Comment: Really good point Matthew

Answer (score 7):

**SQL Server 2012 +:**

Use [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx):

```
CONCAT('$', CAST(AVG(e.[myAmount]) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS 'Total Amount'
```

---

**SQL Server 2008 +:**

[See Tom's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489648/483349)

---

**Note**

You may not want to do this in the query if you ever need to consider multiple currency types. Get the results in a "raw" format and then do conversions in your server business logic (and attach the appropriate currency symbol there, as well).

Comment: +1 on the *Note*. I always recommend having the database deliver raw data, and formatting it as needed when delivering the data to the user.

Answer (score 2):

An implementation that works in SQL Server 2008+

```
SELECT '$' +  CAST(CONVERT(MONEY, AVG(e.myAmount)) AS NVARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just `cast` to varchar something like this:

```
select '$' + CAST (CAST(AVG([myAmount]) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as VARCHAR(13)) AS 'Total Amount' 
from average_test
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99e7f/3/0)